# Matrix limit vs the limit of matrices applied to a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I have just encountered the definition of matrix limit.

Say if $A_{k}$ is a sequence of matrices that converges to matrix $A$ as $k \to \infty$, is it true that $A(x)$ for $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the same as $\lim_{x \to\infty}(A_k(x))$? That is, in one case we first take the matrix at the limit $A$, and apply it to a vector $x$. In the second case we apply each matrix $A_k$ in the sequence to the vector $x$, and take the limit of the vectors. Are the two the same?

Does the above depend on the type of convergence, e.g. norm convergence or convergence for each entry in the matrix?

Further, is this true for linear operators in general and not just matrices?

Comment: If $A_k \to A$ entry-wise, then $A_k x \to Ax$ entry-wise. This follows from basic limit properties, e.g. if $a_k \to a$ and $b_k \to b$ then $a_k x + b_k y \to ax+by$ .